# Image Processing in low quality SEM image

Tags: image-processing

I am not very expirienced in image processing...but have acquired some very noisy SEM images and it's hard to distinguish the particles I want to segment from the background. I know it's a general question but still...can you direct me to how I should go about it?

[image]
thank you in advance
Adi

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of an image. However, SEM noise is often shot noise, so maybe a median filter would be a useful tool.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't load an image because I need a minimal reputation of 10...

Comment: If you can upload it anywhere (e.g. dropbox or whatever) and edit the link into your question, myself or someone else can put the pic in for you)

Comment: thanks you. I uploaded it using dropbox

Comment: If what you want are all the big white dots you can use a Median Filter like @Roger Rowland suggested. After that you could use a threshold to set all background pixel to zero.

Comment: Yes I want to segment the white dots but unfortunately a simple median filter preserves edges but doesn't clear the picture very well. Can you please explain why you think this is shot noise? Someone told me to use an adaptive gaussian filter in small slices of the image and then use k-means for segmentation. I am trying to estimate the noise for this but keep getting different results for different methods- I tried 1) the STD of the different between pixels 2)the average of std of all slices in image...both with different results. Is there a better way to compute?

Comment: I think it's shot noise because I work for a company that makes SEM's and I do a lot of the image processing and analysis work ;-) I can see from the image that you're at high mag with low kV and probe current so you have a very poor SNR which contains shot noise from the electronics. I've started an answer with some examples if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be too specific without knowing what you want to achieve. If it's just improvement of the image in visual terms, a median filter would be my first suggestion. Use a small kernel size to avoid eroding edges too much.

As an example, here is a section of your original unprocessed image:

[image: before]

And here is the same section after applying a median filter with a 2 pixel radius:

[image: after]

It looks to me like the image is also slightly defocused, to which you can attempt some deconvolution algorithms like the Wiener filter, for example.

If you want to process the image in some way, for example to count the blobs (although that image is a really poor starting point), you can threshold it to get a binary image and then use morphological operations to refine the content. For example, I took the median filtered image, thresholded to binary and then performed a morphological **open** operation (an **erode** followed by a **dilate**):

[image: binary]

To refine the segmentation and to split some of the touching particles, you can try a **watershed segmentation** on the binary image, like this:

[image: watershed]

Note that all of these images I produced using [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), if you want to experiment further.

Comment: Thanks Roger! Yes I want to improve the image quality to be able to segment the white blobs. I tried a median filter and weiner deconvolution but the results were not good and as you said, this is a really poor starting point. The weiner filter requires some knowledge of the noise which I don't have.

Comment: @AdiJakten yes I understand only too well! If you want to explore some more advanced noise removal, take a look at [total variation denoising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising) too - there are some C and MATLAB sources out there.

Comment: I can't vote up with reputation of less 15 :\ so will do so later on when it hopefully rises